# How do I catch a StreamTcpException when using akka streams?

Tags: tcp, akka, akka-stream

I created a client to server connection using akka streams with the following code:

```
val connection = Tcp.get(system).outgoingConnection(serverIp, serverPort)
...
connection.join(graph).run(mat)
```

When the server closes or restarts, I receive the following exception on the client-side:

```
Upstream failed. (akka.stream.StreamTcpException: The connection closed with error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
```

I would like to catch this error and handle it (shutting down the client-side actor system). Is this possible? If so, how?

I've tried using a supervision strategy, but that didn't seems to work.

Multiple TCP clients can be connected to the server with this single program. I want to shutdown the client-side actor system when all the TCP clients have disconnected (in any way, exception or otherwise).

Comment: 1. From your example seems you have only one TCP client. How you are creating more connections and clients?

     2. From what I understand you are interested in closing ActorSystem in case all TCP clients are disconnected so you may check whether all streams are finished,so actually you don't have to handle any exception explicitly as you may check if stream is finished. 
If that is acceptable I may help here.

Comment: @ŁukaszGawron , 1. I'm creating more TCP connections by simply putting the said example code inside a for-loop. 2. You are correct, I could check when all the streams are finished. If you're talking about using the "whenComplete" handler, I have tried that. That handler is run once the connection is established, not when the connection is severed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share what is graph and what is mat?